# Should we add "No valuations" to the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

I think we should put "no valuation questions" in FAQ because they're purely opinion-based. The value is specific to the seller and the buyer, and at best local to the time and place that the buyer or seller is in.

I think it would be better to address them explicitly in the FAQ in the hope of having to close fewer of them.

[How much is a Trek Alpha aluminium 58cm road bike worth?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34948/how-much-is-a-trek-alpha-aluminium-58cm-road-bike-worth)

[How much is a mass production aluminium road bike frame worth?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/34279/how-much-is-a-mass-production-aluminium-frame-worth?s=1|1.2870)

[How do I tell if a used bike (craigslist) is worth it?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/32923/how-do-i-tell-if-a-used-bike-craigslist-is-worth-it?s=8|0.1266)

(a lot of ["how much worth" search results](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=how%20much%20worth), in other words)

Comment: I agree and I want to 'bump' this up in the queue. I wanted to refer a questioner to our rationale and we don't really have one in our FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

I concur.

Related - I did like someone's witty answer about aluminium/aluminum being 40 cents per pound, therefore a 10 kilogram bike being worth around $8

Comment: This is why I buy the heaviest BSO I can, for the resale value. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think we should do this, but put a link to something like bicyclebluebook.com and bikepedia.com since they list a lot of models over the years for their new (at the time) price and some estimates for what the bikes go for now.

The numbers are not necessarily reliable in any way, but its the same thing like with Kelly Blue Book for cars -- its a number.

Answer (score 1):

Who has the edit power to change the FAQ? I went to go see if I did it and I don't. I assume that a moderator has to do this?