# Should we add valuations to our list of close reasons?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

We get questions asking us to assess the value of a bicycle relatively frequently. There seems to be [some consensus](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/should-we-add-no-valuations-to-the-faq) that we don't deal with these questions. I was wondering if we should add them to the list of close reasons.

The thing that got me thinking about it was a [recent question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/40907/is-200-a-good-deal-on-a-2006-specialized-transition) that currently has four close votes as off topic as a product recommendation, which doesn't seem quite right. I would think "too broad" or "primarily opinion based" might be better, but neither of those really make it clear to a new user what the problem is.

Note: Stack Exchange allows us three custom close reasons. This would be our third (after product rec and medical advice). So if we wanted to add another after this, one would have to go.

Answer (score 10):

I'd suggest asking (and answering) the general question ***How can I estimate the value of a used bike?***

Any valuation questions could then be closed as duplicates of the general question.

Comment: I think this is an *excellent* idea. Would you like to take a stab at that? It has the potential to build you *a ton* of reputation over time.

Comment: I've added a CW for general used bike buying stuff: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/41040/how-do-i-buy-a-used-bike

Answer (score 5):

Can we edit the existing one from

```
Questions seeking product, service, or learning material
recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become
obsolete quickly."
```

to

```
Questions seeking item valuations, or product/service/learning
material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become
obsolete quickly.
```

And how about an alternative solution like "try asking in the SE Chat room instead."

Comment: I like the idea of expanding the explanation rather than adding a new reason. It means we get the auto-comment, and we generally add more explanation so I think that will work. The goal is to shift the "close question" point back to before they click "post my question" :)

Comment: Does this actually set an autocomment like duplicate does? I'm pretty sure I've used it and not gotten an auto comment.

Comment: @Batman It does. The [question that I mentioned](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/40907/is-200-a-good-deal-on-a-2006-specialized-transition) has now been closed as a product rec. You can see an example there.

Comment: It puts the thing in the yellow box after closing, but when you put close for duplicate, you get "Possible duplicate of ..."when someone casts a close vote.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a good idea to close such questions, but don't we already have sufficient reasons without creating one explicitly?

Comment: That is the question. The fact that we had four people using an incorrect reason on a single question makes me think we might need something more specific.

Comment: There are already enough for _me_

Comment: Which existing close reason do you think is appropriate?

Comment: Primarily opinion-based